# Confusion over definition of closure of a set

Tags: real-analysis, definition

Someone called Bob told me:

> Definition of closure: $\overline{A}=\{x_0: \forall \epsilon>0,
> > (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \cap A =\emptyset\}$

From https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1776563/edit

They said:

> Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be given. The closure of A is
>   $\overline{A}=\left\{z:\forall\epsilon>0,
> > D_{\epsilon}\left(z\right)\cap A\neq\phi\right\}$

Royden said

> $x$ is a point of closure of $E$ if every open interval containing $x$
>   also contains a point of $E$.

My interpretation is that Bob is wrong according to Royden and the link.

therefore Bob should have defined it as  $\bar{A}=\{x_0: \forall \epsilon>0, (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$?

Who is right? What is closure?

Comment: You are correct and Bob's definition is silly is that's really what they told you

Comment: I'm presuming that there was some miscommunication between you and Bob.

Comment: @DonThousand Probably the best comment I read on this site. Please tell me this pawn was intended.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker Yes, that's the joke

Comment: @AlexMathers Does the definition of closure apply to both open and closed sets? Suppose either A is open or closed or neither open nor closed, then $\bar{A}=\{x_0: \forall \epsilon>0, (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$?